# how to run grpc client in python and server in cpp?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-c++

I am trying to work with client.py , server.cpp and a make file. I am not understanding how to run the files and work on grpc with these files. Is it possible for anyone to help me understand this concept and work with the client, server and protobuf?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of gRPC is to enable protocol based communication between cross platform services. Means your CPP server can communicate with python client. Ref: [Official gRPC Documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/#overview)

1. First step is to [write a `.proto` file](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) which is an agreement between server and client on what attributes should a request / response for a particular RPC method should contain.
2. Now one can implement server, client in any language of their choice. **As long as server & client agree on single proto file**, underlying process is abstracted by gRPC framework and it just works!!!

> For fastest hands-on, Refer to quick start guides of gRPC for [c++](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/), [python](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/) to implement cross platform server, client.